# TeamCity API. Do not run new build if build is already in progress

Tags: teamcity, jira

How to prevent the launch of the build code branch, if the build code from a branch is already in progress?

Build runs through API from JIRA Automation (Send Webhook Request) to:
`http://teamcity.url/app/rest/buildQueue?buildTypeId=<buildTypeId>`

**Request Body:**

```
<build branchName="{{issue.fields.branch}}">
    <buildType id="<buildTypeId>"/>
</build>
```

**Problem:** since the JIRA does not know anything about whether the build is running or not on the TeamCity, the JIRA starts the build again if rule was executed

Comment: https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk/uploads/projects/261847.jpg

Comment: try to use snapshot dependency. I think it will help you

Comment: did it help you? any news?

Comment: we have not tried how we will try your solution - I'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I checked and it works

Just create the base configuration which you want to run. Let's say **A**

Create the configuration **B** which depends from **A** as Slapshot dependency with params

- `Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` - checked
- `Only use successful builds from suitable ones` - checked
- `Run build on the same agent` - unchecked
- `Make build start of faild` - both

[image]

How it works? 
You will trigger the configuration **B**. B depends from A. B checked that the A already has a build with some branch and commit, so, no need to run one more, so let's finish.

if A has a new commit then the **B** see that A has changes, so let's start a new Build A, wait for finish.

If A failed then B also will be failed.

p.s. now you should trigger **B** instead of **A**.